# Equal spaced, full width menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu with four options which I need to sit below an image like so:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                        This is an image                      |
----------------------------------------------------------------
Menu 1               Menu 2             Menu 3             Menu4
```

These size is responsive, so I'm positioning the menu items dynamically. My problem is how to calculate the menu widths so that the spacing is equal as well as Menu1 and Menu4 meeting the edge of the image.

Comment: you don't need jquery/javascript for that

Comment: Let me prove you wrong, just a sec :-)

Comment: Does this work: http://jsfiddle.net/Gv7fZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do it entirely in CSS

Check this **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Gv7fZ/

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <img src="<put-image-url-here>">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="menuitem">Menu 1</div>
        <div class="menuitem">Menu 2</div>
        <div class="menuitem">Menu 3</div>
        <div class="menuitem">Menu 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    margin: auto;    
    display: table-cell;
}
.menuitem {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
}
.menuitem:first-child {
    text-align: left;  
    width: 16%;    
}
.menuitem:last-child {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;   
    width: 16%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Will you ever have any more than 4 menu items at a given time? If not you can easily just wrap the links within an unorded and assign the `<li>` widths to 25% each. See the below example:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: The right-hand side of Menu4 does not align with the right-hand side of the block.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fixed number of items, you can work out the percentage each one needs to be (like [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13137888/370103) has shown).

If the amount of menu items can vary, you can use jQuery to determine the widths:

```
var imgWidth = $(".img").width();
var itemWidth = imgWidth / $("ul.menu li").length;

$("ul.menu li").width(itemWidth);
```

Here I'm getting the image's width, then dividing the width by the number of `li` elements, then applying this value as the width for each `li` element.

**See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rwvhG/**

---

In terms of the alignment, this can be done with CSS:

```
ul li
{
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

ul li:first-child
{
    text-align:left;
}

ul li:last-child
{
    text-align:right;
}
```

**See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rwvhG/1/**

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty close. The spacing still isn't quite equal and adding more elements would break it.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use css to set 25% width this will not work so well if the menu items text width is very different. If you want it to be really exact then try the following:

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>​
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready( function( ) {

    var widths = 0;
    var items = $(".menu > li");
    var menu_width = items.eq(0).parent().width();

    // total width of all existing li
    items.each( function( ) {
        widths += $(this).width( );
    });        

    var gap = parseInt( ( menu_width - widths ) / ( items.length - 1 ) );

    // set widths of list items except for last one. Last li gets pushed to edge
    items.slice( 0, -1 ).each( function( ) { 
        $(this).width( $(this).width() + gap );
    });
});
```

​Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UEcd6/1/)

However, if the width of your menu items is pretty much the same you will probably be better off using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If your layout is responsive then set your menu items to be 25% width each and then set the last child to be text-align:right so that it lines up with the right margin.

```
#Menu ul li {text-align:left;display:inline-block;width:25%}
#Menu ul li:last-child {text-align:right}
```

Comment: This doesn't result in equal spacing.